# How do I convert a binary array to its 2's complement?

Tags: c, arrays, twos-complement

I'm having trouble with trying to convert to 2's complement. I know what the problem is but I can't figure out how to fix it. 
The problem is the two if statements in the inner for loop because one changes the value to 0 and then the other one changes it back to 1. I tried changing it to if and else if but it got even worse with the values.

```
/*
 Signed array[] contains digits of 0 or 1 and at index 0 of the array
 is where it is determined positive or negative. the parameter size is
 the number of digits. Returns the 2's complement of the given array
 with the same number of digits (size of array).
 */

int* signed2Complement2(int signed_binary[], int size){

   int i, j, k;

   int negative = 1;

   int size2 = size;

   int begin_of_array = 0;

   int complement_binary[size];

   if(signed_binary[begin_of_array] == 0){

      negative = 0;

      printf("Is positive %d\n", negative);

   }

   else printf("Is negative %d\n", negative);


   for(i = size-1; i>=0; i--){

       complement_binary[i] = signed_binary[i];

       printf("Binary at %d is: %d\n", i, complement_binary[i]);

   }

   for(j = size2 -1; j>=0; j--){

       if(complement_binary[j] == 1){

          for(k = j; k>=0;k--){

                if(complement_binary[k] == 1){

                complement_binary[k] = 0;

                printf("Binary at %d is: %d\n", k, complement_binary[k]);

             }

             if(complement_binary[k] == 0){

                complement_binary[k] = 1;

                printf("Binary at %d is: %d\n", k, complement_binary[k]);

             }

          }

       }

    }



return complement_binary;

}
```

Comment: `return complement_binary;` will definitely lead to dangling pointer problem in the calling function. You may want use `malloc` to allocate memory and return that instead of using a VLA.

Comment: so instead have it like this?
int *complement_binary = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

Comment: `int* complement_binary = malloc(..;`.

Comment: well i tried using malloc but when i input 1111 it doesn't switch it to 0001 so its still the same problem as b4.

Comment: @Patrick_Webb Why two nested loops?

Comment: because i have to go through the inputted array to find the first 1 in the array then i start another for loop at that position of the first 1 so i can flip the next values.

Comment: @Patrick_Webb Feel free for any queries.

Comment: sure bud im always open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You are confused my friend.To calculate two's complement of a binary number,there are two steps:

1.Take the one's complement.

2.Add 1 to the one's complement.

So my c code would be:

```
int* signed2Complement2(int signed_binary[], int size)
    {
       int i, j, k;
       int negative = 1;
       int size2 = size;
       int begin_of_array = 0;
       int *complement_arr=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
       if(signed_binary[begin_of_array] == 0){
          negative = 0;
          printf("Is positive %d\n", negative);
       }
       else printf("Is negative %d\n", negative);
       for(i=size-1;i>=0;--i)
          if(signed_binary[i]==0)
            complement_arr[i]=1;
          else complement_arr[i]=0;
       i=size-1;
       int carry=1;
       while(i>=0&&carry==1)
       {
           if(complement_arr[i]==0)
           {
              complement_arr[i]=1;carry=0;
           }
           else
           {
               complement_arr[i]=0;carry=1;
           }
           --i;
       }
       return complement_arr;
    }
```

Comment: ohh i see what you mean my bad bud

Comment: i did now but since i just made an account it said until my rep is 15 my votes wont change anything.